# Is it possible to block the size and/or position of a task "ballon" in a SSIS dtsx with Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: ssis, resize, task

Every time I modify a name of task in SSIS its "balloon" gets resized to the minimum width possible to show the text of the name.
I'd like to have all the sizes of my tasks the same as it would look more orderly.
Unfortunately after a general "FORMAT/Make Same Size/Both" I have to correct many tasks if I touch them because they got resized.

Is there a way to block the aspect of a target balloon?

Answer (score 0):

This is default behavior and cannot be changed as far as I know. I checked the options too and there is nothing that would allow you to stop this behavior.